# Making Org-Mode to remember folding?

Tags: linux, debian, emacs, org-mode, to-do

I am a recent convert to Org-Mode. I like it a lot but I am having an issue with reopening files. When I open a org file, Org-Mode does not remember the folding which sux, because I have to resetup everything properly to my liking.

Is there a way to make Org-Mode to remember the folding when the file is opened next time?

I am using 
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.5) on Debian Jessie.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible out of the box since you would have to use an additional file to store that information. What I did instead is setting the `org-startup-folded` variable to `nil` so to start unfolded, which I think is a better default.

See `C-h v org-startup-folded`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is sad that Org-Mode does not care about remebering this stuff. ALl the other outliners I ever used remembers this stuff fine. I personally have no problem using a dot file that keeps these settings in the same folder as my original file.

Comment: Here is a quote from the manual as to frequently asked questions -- http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html -- **Can I save/restore the visibility state of an org-mode buffer?  Well, no—at least not automatically. You can, however, control the visibility of an org-file or of individual trees by adding instructions to your org file. See http://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-cycling.html#Visibility-cycling for more information.**